# Bootstrap Dropdowns Issue ASP.Net VB

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently attempting to create a template that allows the use of the Bootstrap Menu along with the grid system for responsive design. However, I obtained the latest LESS files and compiled the full version of the JS. Yet, this is failing to open the dropdowns within the menu, along with the fact it will not open the menu dropdown when brought to mobile mode size.

I need help to figure out why I cannot get the code to load correctly, if anyone else has had this problem setting up!

Here are the pages:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Main.master.vb" Inherits="Template.Main" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title></title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>  
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
            <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="google.com">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="Redirect.aspx">Redirect</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
                        <%-- Start <row> then <col> for pages --%>
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <div class="container">

            <%--  Holds the entire Grid--%>
            <div class="row">
                <%-- Row needed per columns--%>
                <div class="col-sm-12">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I ended up finding a fresh copy of bootstrap.js not made by my system here:

<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

But when i take that same link, and save the file within my Script folder, it does not want to load. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, in case anyone else runs into this problem. The  calls i have do not include a type="text/javascript". Once that is added in, they work like magic. I feel a bit stupid for the overlooking mistake